# Compare quadratic coefficients between group levels from mixed effects model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, post-hoc, polynomial, lsmeans

I'm hoping I can find some advice on this question. I have repeated measures of an outcome variable `yvar` where the trend over `xvar` changes with a factor `SF`. At lower values of SF, yvar is more linear. At higher values of SF, yvar is more curvilinear.

I've modelled yvar with a quadratic polynomial.

```
lmm <- lm(yvar ~ SF * poly(xvar, 2), data = df)

# visualise
ggplot(df, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, colour = as.factor(SF))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

My main question is: at what value of SF does yvar become significantly better described by a quadratic function than linear?

I think I can answer this by comparing the quadratic coefficient to zero for each level of SF? Does this sound appropriate?

I'm not sure I'm interpreting the results of `emmeans::emtrends` correctly, and would appreciate any advice.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
library(tidyverse)

# df provided below
lmm <- lm(yvar ~ SF * poly(xvar, 2), data = df)

emt <- 
    emtrends(
        lmm,
        specs = ~ SF * degree,
        var = "xvar",
        max.degree = 2,
        at = list(SF = seq(4, 16, 4)), # simplify levels of SF
        adjust = "sidak",
        infer = TRUE
    )

# Remove the linear coefs to focus on quadratic coefs
emt_quadratic <- emt[-c(1:4)]
emt_quadratic

> emt_quadratic
 SF degree    xvar.trend      SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
  4 quadratic   -0.00164 0.00223 160 -0.00725  0.00396  -0.739  0.9158
  8 quadratic   -0.00613 0.00153 160 -0.00998 -0.00228  -4.013  0.0004
 12 quadratic   -0.01062 0.00178 160 -0.01510 -0.00614  -5.976  <.0001
 16 quadratic   -0.01511 0.00273 160 -0.02197 -0.00824  -5.544  <.0001

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 4 estimates 
P value adjustment: sidak method for 4 tests 


df <- 
    structure(list(
        ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
               7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
               10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
               12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 
               14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 
               16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
               18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
               20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21),
        xvar = c(29, 42, 57, 
                 72, 86, 100, 25, 37, 50, 62, 75, 88, 100, 19, 29, 38, 48, 57, 
                 66, 76, 86, 95, 100, 21, 31, 42, 52, 62, 73, 83, 94, 99, 20, 
                 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 22, 33, 44, 56, 66, 78, 89, 
                 100, 21, 32, 42, 52, 64, 74, 84, 94, 100, 20, 29, 38, 48, 58, 
                 68, 78, 87, 96, 100, 23, 33, 44, 56, 67, 78, 89, 100, 24, 36, 
                 47, 59, 71, 84, 95, 100, 27, 40, 54, 67, 80, 94, 100, 25, 37, 
                 50, 62, 75, 87, 100, 23, 35, 46, 58, 69, 80, 92, 100, 20, 30, 
                 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 27, 40, 53, 67, 80, 94, 100, 25, 
                 38, 50, 62, 75, 87, 100, 26, 39, 52, 64, 77, 90, 99, 30, 44, 
                 58, 74, 88, 100, 25, 37, 50, 62, 75, 88, 100, 18, 27, 36, 45, 
                 54, 64, 72, 82, 92, 100, 25, 37, 50, 62, 75, 87, 100), 
        yvar = c(42, 
                 36, 31, 26, 20, 14, 45, 44, 39, 34, 28, 24, 18, 64, 68, 70, 66, 
                 56, 46, 37, 27, 22, 16, 65, 72, 74, 70, 64, 56, 48, 41, 33, 60, 
                 70, 68, 66, 60, 44, 38, 34, 28, 50, 50, 46, 42, 30, 21, 16, 10, 
                 44, 47, 43, 37, 33, 24, 18, 8, 5, 64, 62, 57, 50, 44, 36, 26, 
                 23, 20, 17, 56, 69, 66, 60, 56, 48, 36, 23, 52, 61, 62, 58, 52, 
                 42, 32, 26, 86, 84, 83, 74, 58, 46, 44, 50, 48, 43, 34, 18, 10, 
                 8, 56, 66, 68, 68, 62, 55, 44, 34, 62, 58, 54, 50, 44, 38, 30, 
                 20, 11, 46, 42, 40, 34, 28, 22, 10, 82, 81, 80, 76, 64, 47, 26, 
                 74, 81, 84, 82, 72, 58, 41, 82, 87, 86, 82, 76, 66, 52, 50, 42, 
                 38, 30, 25, 16, 50, 47, 44, 41, 34, 29, 20, 14, 12, 10, 30, 34, 
                 50, 69, 72, 54, 31),
        SF = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6, 6, 
                6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
                16, 16, 16, 16, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
                15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 12, 12, 12, 
                12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                6, 6, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
                13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                4, 4, 4, 4, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)), 
        row.names = c(NA, -166L),  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I think this answers my question, that the quadratic coefficient for SF = 4 is not different from 0? I would go look closer between SF %in% 4:8 to see where it becomes significant, and interpret the meaningfulness across SF levels.

When I compare contrasts between levels of SF, why do they come back with the same p.value? e.g. I would expect SF4 to be more different from SF16 than SF8. This is probably something basic that I don't understand?

```
> contrast(emt_quadratic, "revpairwise")
 contrast                        estimate      SE  df t.ratio p.value
 SF8 quadratic - SF4 quadratic   -0.00449 0.00131 160  -3.419  0.0044
 SF12 quadratic - SF4 quadratic  -0.00897 0.00263 160  -3.419  0.0044
 SF12 quadratic - SF8 quadratic  -0.00449 0.00131 160  -3.419  0.0044
 SF16 quadratic - SF4 quadratic  -0.01346 0.00394 160  -3.419  0.0044
 SF16 quadratic - SF8 quadratic  -0.00897 0.00263 160  -3.419  0.0044
 SF16 quadratic - SF12 quadratic -0.00449 0.00131 160  -3.419  0.0044

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

How then could I test which individual levels of SF were different from each other? Say I want to know what delta change in SF will cause significant differences in the resulting profile of yvar?

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I think a faceted plot with `+ facet_grid(~SF)` is more informative. A couple of things I notice right away: the variances vary across SF and something seems to be off with SF = 13. (Is each group a composition of multiple replicates?) Anyway, because of the variance disparities I suggest that a simple approach is to analyze each SF groups separately: the mean params are already SF-specific & if you make the sigma SF-specific also, the dataset "splits". And then you can compare a linear model with a quadratic model with for example likelihood ratio test, one SF group at a time.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah well spotted, I condensed repeated measures to simplify the example. Maybe that changes things? Sorry, could you explain your suggestion to analyse SF groups separately? SF is interval data >0 (real world values ~2-20) and constant for each participant between measures. Do you mean something like bin SF into e.g. 4 discrete groups and analyse a separate lm (or lmer) model for each? Or a separate post-hoc analysis from the full lm/lmer model?

Comment: It seems I've misread the question since I understood SF to be a factor variable with discrete levels that just happen to be labeled 4, 5, and so on. Instead SF is a continuous variable itself. (Also, *emtrends* is usually used for an interaction between one continuous and one factor variable?) Perhaps you can explain in more detail the data, incl. what the repeated measurements are, and the purpose of the analysis.

Comment: In your follow-up question, that is because you have `SF` in your model as a linear term interacting with your polynomial; i.e., that the polynomial effects change linearly with `SF`, meaning that any comparison of those effects is the same for a given increment of `SF`.

Comment: @RussLenth ah ok thanks. So this isn't the way to ask that question. @dipetkov thanks, ya I did have a factor variable in there, but they're strongly colinear in my dataset so I wanted to see how `SF` alone would predict `yvar`. I'll have to re-think how to approach this question from ground up. In general I want to ask how the 'curviness' of the response is related to `SF`.

Comment: I wonder if you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Typically, people address these kinds of questions by testing contrasts. How about if you forget the polynomal models and just use ordinary factorial models, then follow up by testing `poly` contrasts? Or comparison of those polynomial contrasts?

Comment: Thanks. Not going to lie though, I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Run linear lme4 models on the factors I'm interested in, and compare `emmeans::contrast(model, "poly")` from each?